# Event loop and synchronous blocking

Tags: javascript, synchronous, event-loop

I am going through "JS For Impatient Programmers" and I came across the following code.
I am trying to understand the synchronous nature and why `Blocking...` waits to be set after `sleep(5000)`.
 I believe the intention of the code was for `Blocking...` to appear on the screen while the blocking occurs but that is not that actual response when I input it in JSFiddle

```js
document.getElementById('block')
  .addEventListener('click', doBlock);

function doBlock(event) {
  setStatus('Blocking...');
  sleep(5000);
  setStatus('Done');
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const start = Date.now();
  while ((Date.now() - start) < milliseconds);
}

function setStatus(status) {
  document.getElementById('statusMessage')
    .textContent = status;
}
```

```html
<a id="block" href="#">Block</a>
<div id="statusMessage"></div>
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: The `sleep` function "blocks" because it's executing a loop for 5 seconds straight - it's actually executing code (even if it's code that does nothing), therefore nothing else in the browser can run (JS is single-threaded). Needless to say, it is an utterly terrible idea to do anything like this in a real website.

Comment: The browser is never given time to to update the DOM nodes due to the JavaScript entering a tight loop without returning control to the event loop.  The exact behavior will be browser (and in some cases version) specific.

Answer (score 0):

May I share my findings with the following **slightly altered** HTML/JS code.

1. Chromium Version 73.0.3683.75 (openSUSE Build) (64-bit) works as expected.
2. Firefox Developer Edition 67b6 (64-bit) **occasionally** works as expected.
3. Firefox Stable Quantum 60.6.1 ESR (64-bit) still doesn't work as expected.

However, if you move to a `const delayBlocking = 50` milliseconds delay, it also shows the "Blocking..." on the Firefox Stable Quantum 60.6.1 ESR browser.

My interpretation is (according to what Mark said in a comment) that the browser must be given the time to update the DOM. The browser must be able to render at least one frame showing the "Blocking..." status message rendered before entering the blocked state (here for 5 seconds). This can be done with a suitable adjusted setTimeout as is shown below. -- Regards, M.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="block" href="#">Block</a>
    <div id="statusMessage"></div>
    <button>Click me!</button>

    <script>
     document.getElementById('block')
             .addEventListener('click', doBlock);

     function doBlock(event) {
         setStatus('Blocking...');

         // Introducing some ...
         const delayBlocking = 0;

         setTimeout(function() {
             sleep(5000);
             setStatus('Done');
         }, delayBlocking);
     }

     function sleep(milliseconds) {
         const start = Date.now();
         while ((Date.now() - start) < milliseconds);
     }

     function setStatus(status) {
         document.getElementById('statusMessage')
                 .textContent = status;
     }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```